Is $ H^*(X;\mathbb{F})\otimes_{\mathbb{F}}S$ isomorphic as a ring to $H^*(X;S)$?
Let $S$ be an algebra over a field $\mathbb{F}$, and let $X$ be a manifold with finitely generated homology groups. Define multiplication on $ H^*(X;\mathbb{F})\otimes_{\mathbb{F}}S $ by $(a_1\otimes b_1,a_2\otimes b_2)\mapsto a_1\cup a_2\otimes b_1 \cdot b_2. $
Is $H^*(X;\mathbb{F})\otimes_{\mathbb{F}}S$ isomorphic as a ring to $H^*(X;S)$ ?
My attempt: As the homology groups are finitely generated, and we take cohomology with field coefficients, We have as $\mathbb{F}$ modules $ H^*(X;\mathbb{F})\otimes_{\mathbb{F}}S\cong \hom_{\mathbb{F}}\left(H_*(X;\mathbb{F}),S\right)\cong H^*(X;S).$
Is this also a ring homomorphism?

It is true, but I prefer an isomorphism which avoids homology. It is more explicit. There are so many UCTs, and your question remind me of this one. We can change coefficients between cohomology groups in an exact sequence not involving the homology. Let me make the isomorphism explicit and then check it’s an algebra isomorphism. I take $S$ to be a commutative $\Bbb F$-algebra. If you want to cut to the chase, see the last paragraph.
Let $C_{\Bbb F}=\Bbb Z[\mathrm{Sing}(X)]\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb F$ be the singular complex of $X$ with coefficients in $\Bbb F$. Cohomology with coefficients in an $\Bbb F$-vector space can be computed by $C_{\Bbb F}$, so work entirely in the category of $\Bbb F$-vector spaces now. By a different UCT, we know $C_{\Bbb F}$ has finitely generated homology. Among all chain complexes $D$, there are natural homomorphisms $H^n(D;\Bbb F)\otimes_{\Bbb F}S\to H^n(\hom_{\Bbb F}(D;\Bbb F)\otimes_{\Bbb F}S)$ and $\hom_{\Bbb F}(D;\Bbb F)\otimes_{\Bbb F}S\to\hom_{\Bbb F}(D;S)$. The first one acts on pure tensors by mapping a cocycle $\phi$ and an element $s$ to the class of $\phi\otimes s$ and the second one acts by taking a pure tensor $f\otimes s$ to the homomorphism $d\mapsto f(d)\cdot s$.
Overall we have a natural transformation $H^\bullet(-;\Bbb F)\otimes_{\Bbb F}S\to H^\bullet(-;S)$. Now, as we are over a field, $S$ is flat and the first homomorphism I mentioned is always an isomorphism. For modules over a general commutative ring, the second homomorphism is an isomorphism of complexes when $D$ is free and finitely generated in each degree, or when $S$ is finitely presented (as a module/vector space) and $D$ is projective in each degree. To make extra safe, we can (see Spanier) find a homotopy equivalence $C_{\Bbb F}\simeq L$ where $L$ is free and finitely generated in each degree and use naturality and the fact our overall homomorphism is an isomorphism for $L$ to conclude it is also an isomorphism for $C_{\Bbb F}$. In general over a PID (see the linked theorem, where a complicating Ext term also appears) we would need the fact that homotopy equivalences are preserved by all additive functors, but over a field everything is flat and injective so just a quasi-isomorphism would do.
So if $S$ is finite dimensional or if $X$ has finitely generated integral homology (or more weakly, finitely generated homology with $\Bbb F$-coefficients), the following procedure: $[\phi]\otimes s\mapsto(\sigma\mapsto\phi(\sigma)\cdot s)$ induces an isomorphism $H^\bullet(X;\Bbb F)\otimes_{\Bbb F}S\cong H^{\bullet}(X;S)$ of graded vector spaces. However this explicit formula makes it extremely clear that, if $S$ is commutative, it is an isomorphism of commutative graded rings; if $X$ is path-connected you even get to say it is an isomorphism of commutative graded $S$-algebras, because now both objects contain $S$ in their zeroth degree as a subring. The explicit formula for the isomorphism also makes it clear it is natural both in the space $X$ and the $\Bbb F$-algebra $S$, among spaces/algebras satisfying the requirements. Without hypotheses, this map is still a map of rings - it just might not be an isomorphism.

I don't understand why the first map is well-defined. Is the image of the map not  an element of $H_n\left(\operatorname{hom}{\mathbb{F}}(D ; \mathbb{F}) \otimes{\mathbb{F}} S\right)$ ?

@Elad This is a very innocent matter of indexing conventions. It is either $H_{\color{red}{-n}}$ or $H^n$. If I insist on cohomological grading of $(+1)$ and that $\hom_{\Bbb F}(D;\Bbb F)$ is a cochain complex with $n$th degree term $\hom_{\Bbb F}(D_n;\Bbb F)$, then what I said is fine. You have to keep track of grading conventions but they’re fundamentally unimportant so long as you make sure you’re consistent with yourself and the statements of other people

So you write $H^n$ because $\operatorname{hom}{\mathbb{F}}(D ; \mathbb{F}) $ is a cochain complex ? You don't dualize the complex  $\operatorname{hom}{\mathbb{F}}(D ; \mathbb{F})$ here, if i understand correctly

The first isomorphism is the UCT in homology, right?

@Elad I write $H^n$ because I want to think of it as a cochain complex, yes. This is why we write $H^n$ for spaces too. $H^n(D;\Bbb F)$ is shorthand for $H^n(\hom_{\Bbb F}(D_\bullet;\Bbb F))$. The first isomorphism can come from the UCT for homology if you insist, but actually it’s just by definition of flatness (and this is more general and important to understand than the UCT for homology); tensoring with $S$ is an exact functor and induces isomorphisms on homology (specifically the map that I wrote is the canonical one and is an iso by flatness)
